# Get original entity in a constraint

Tags: entities

Is it possible to get the original entity in a constraint?

**Use case**: create a constraint on which item can be deleted in a multi value field

Comment: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/300223/custom-field-validator-comparing-original-and-new-values/300225#300225

Comment: Many thanks!!! This is working so nicely. How can I accept this answer!!